# How can I set a persistent bash variable?

Tags: bash

I use the following procedure to set up a shortcut for accessing directory

```
$ pwd
$ user/home/somefolder/somefolder1
$ export SHORTCUT=$PWD
```

Now if I am in my home directory and type

```
$ pwd
$ user/home
$ cd $SHORTCUT
$ pwd
$ user/home/somefolder/somefolder1
```

But this method works only for one session and if I restart the terminal the above set  shortcut does not seem to work. Is this the way it's supposed to happen  or am I doing something wrong? Also if it works this way, is there a way to permanently set this shortcut?

Answer (score 2):

Type the following from the terminal

`gedit ~/.bashrc`

This will open a window

Type this as the last line and save the file and close gedit.

`export SHORTCUT=user/home/somefolder/somefolder1`

Now close the terminal and open it again.

You can straight away do `cd $SHORTCUT`

Answer (score 0):

if the directory is fixed, use an alias

```
alias cdshortcut='cd user/...'
```

If you want to be able to set an arbitrary directory and have it persist:

```
shortcut   () { pwd > ~/.shortcut; }
cdshortcut () { cd "$(< ~/.shortcut)"; }
```